# 2PL / 3PL annotation on arc in technical drawing

Tags: technical-drawing

I found a technical drawing of a popular guitar shape online and I'm having trouble to understand a certain annotation on some arcs in the drawing. It basically says stuff like "0.43R 2PL" or "3PL" (see attached).

any idea what this could mean? My current guess is that it means that there are X PL other curves in the loop that have the same radius.

[image]

[Drawing Source](http://www.tdpri.com/threads/d-size-tele-body-blueprint-files-here.74504/page-30#post-6860876)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. "0.430R 2PL" means there are two places where there is a curve with the given radius. Usually it is obvious from looking at the complete drawing where all the curves are - for example in the OP's complete drawing, http://www.tdpri.com/attachments/tele_body_drawing_reve-1-pdf.347484/, the part being referred to is symmetrical (though it is oriented at an angle to the symmetry axes of the complete object).

This is more commonly used for things like small holes, where you might see something like "0.1R 36PL" rather than each one of the 36 holes being dimensioned individually. There are some examples of this on the OP's complete drawing.

Comment: Would you also happen to know the meaning of the "C" "CL" and "CL Datum" coming of the horizontal centerline?